# Python subprocess.Popen scapy

Tags: python, subprocess, scapy

I'm running a scapy pcap analyzer from p = subprocess.Popen(run_cmd, shell==True, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

The script runs correctly, unless there is an error with the pcap file. If the pcap file doesn't work for whatever reason, I get the following:

raise Scapy_Exception("Not a pcap capture file (bad magic)")

Anyone know of a good way to handle these errors? My goal is to write the error to a file so I can reference it later. I will be dumping a ton of pcaps at once, so if some don't work, I don't want the errors being printed to the screen. Just outputted to a file if they occur. I assume this has to do with stdout, but how can I catch these errors?

I have tried if "proc.returncode != 0": print "ERROR"
and the same for "proc.poll() != 0". No luck with either of those.

Thanks for any insight the community may have.

Comment: Why are you running scapy as a subprocess instead of using its api?

Comment: I'm calling a script that uses scapy. The main program analyzes all types of files based on extension. Pcaps are analyzed using scapy.

Comment: Is the script catching the errors?

Comment: No it is not. That's the root of the problem. I need an effective way from the parent script to know when one of the scripts run on a child process doesn't finish correctly.

Comment: Can you import the script as a module and then run its main function inside a `try` block?  Can you edit your question to include the source of the script?

Comment: Why are you not catching the errors in the script? There is a very simple way to know if the script threw an error, use check_call but you should be catching the error in the actual script

Comment: I thin the try except may work well for this scenario. Will work things around and let you all know.

Comment: You can also log the errors in the except

Comment: I ended up using a combination of the above comments. I edited the original script, imported it as an api, and caught errors using a try except. Works great! Thanks.